# Minimizing a Composite function

Tags: python-3.x, function

I'm kinda new to python, and I'm trying to minimize the function "fun" that is a composite of "Velo" (also a composite of "area"), but it is giving me de error: TypeError: fun() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'q', 'ro', and 'mi'

```
from math import pi
import scipy.optimize


    def area (r):
        return pi*r**2
    
    def velo(a,q):
        a = area(r)
        return q/a
    
    def fun (r, q, ro, mi):
        v = velo (q,a)
        fun = (ro*v*r)/mi
        return fun
    
    
    x0 = [2,3,5,6]
    
    res = scipy.optimize.minimize(fun, x0)
    print(res)
```

Can someone help out here?

Answer (score 0):

Many things to say here, I will try to answer properly.

**Environment**

Which IDE are you using? I advise you VSCode for example, as it underlines some mistakes it can detect, great for typos aswell.

**Local variables**

In python, variables are defined locally in functions. It means that the variable r in `a = area(r)` is not defined in your velo function.

The same mistake occurs in `v = velo(q,a)`, as a is not defined in the fun function. I advise you to check these mistakes first.

**Answer to your specific question**

The error is raised because the array is considered one argument. I will transform your code (with is not working because of the previous points) but solves your error

```
def fun(array):
    r, q, ro, mi = array
    v = velo (q,a)
    res = (ro*v*r)/mi
    return res
    
x0 = np.array([2,3,4,5])

res = scipy.optimize.minimize(fun, x0)
```